# Ssh - Find files with no associated pictures

Tags: bash, terminal, find

Suppose I have a directory with many .html and .jpg files.

```
/smith.jpg
/smith.html
/subfolder/katy.jpg
/subfolder/katy.html
/subfolder/ally.html
/john- stevenson.html
```

.jpg files and .html files are related by name. I need a command that finds outputs `/subfolder/ally.html` and `/john- stevenson.html` because they do not have an associated `.jpg` file.

I intended to get a list of `.html` files and another list of `.jpg` files. Then, check if the an `.html` file has a corresponding `.jpg` file.

This is how I am building the two lists:

```
$ htmlList=$(find . -type f -iname '*.html');  jpgList=$(find . -type f -iname '*.jpg');
```

At this point, I'm missing the part to check if set 1 has an associated name in set 2. Also, how do I check for special characters? Any gotchas?

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: What does the question have to do with ssh?

Comment: @Cyrus I'm working on a secure shell. Probably should've put shell instead of ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```sh
find . -name '*.html' | while read i; do if [ \! -e "${i%html}jpg" ] ; then echo $i; fi ; done
```